# How to reverse a linkedList iteratively, understanding the code I found online

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, swap, iteration

I am trying to code different interview questions. A very classic question is reversing a singly linked list.
I found this code online and I commented it, but the point where we swap pointers, I don't really get what is happening.

```
public static LinkedList iterativeReverse(LinkedList linkedList) {

    if (linkedList == null || linkedList.next == null) {  //We check if the list is 
                                                           empty or has one node and
                                                           accordingly we return the list if it were the case
        return linkedList;
    }

    LinkedList prevNode, currNode, nextNode; //Three pointers 
    prevNode = null; // Are those pointers 
    nextNode = null; // temporary pointers for the swapping?
    currNode = linkedList; //is this the node pointing to head that is going to eventually point to null?

    while (currNode != null) {  // As long as we haven't reached the end of the list
        nextNode = currNode.next; //here it gets complicated for me, I don't understand what is happening
        currNode.next = prevNode;
        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = nextNode;
    }

    return prevNode;
}
```

Could please someone set me on the right track of approaching this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: If you have a source level debugger, you could create a list and step through the code. On the first loop, nextNode is set to linkedList.next, then linkedList.next is set to null, then prevNode is set to linkedList, and currNode is set to linkedList.next.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a linked list like this a-->b-->c , with the `prevNode` points to `a` and `currNode` point to `b`.

So `nextNode = currNode.next;` will equivalent to point `nextNode` to `c`.

In order to reverse the linked list, we need to change the direction of the link a-->b to b-->a, and this is what happened in:

`currNode.next = prevNode;`

Now, the only job left is update `prevNode` to b and `curNode` to c, and repeat the process.

```
prevNode = currNode;
currNode = nextNode;
```